# Angular (or something else) isn't saving JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: angularjs, spring, cookies

I'm setting up a simple authentication service for my angular website using Spring for my backend and I have a following problem.

When I send a cross domain get request with credentials (REST controller on backend), I get authorized by Spring Security, I get a JSESSION cookie and all is fine. What's not fine is that the cookie isn't saved and I can't access it in any way I could think of to save it manually.

Am I missing something here? If you need additional information, I'd be glad to provide it.

@Edit
I have Set-Cookie header in my response:

```
(...)
Server  
WildFly/8
Set-Cookie  
JSESSIONID=CODE; path=/PATH
(...)
```